# FastAPI celery beat not able to locate app to schedule task

Tags: python, redis, celery, fastapi

I'm trying to schedule a task in celery.

celery.py inside the directory tasks

```
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from celery import Celery

from my_app.config import async_session
from my_app.tasks.tasks import sync_excel_with_db

load_dotenv()

REDIS_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL')
RABBIT_MQ_URL = os.environ.get('RABBIT_MQ_URL')

celery_app = Celery(
    'tasks',
    broker=REDIS_URL,
    include=['my_app.tasks']
)

celery_app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'sync_excel_with_db': {
        'task': 'sync_excel_with_db_task',
        'schedule': 15.0,
    },
}


@celery_app.task()
async def sync_excel_with_db_task():
    await sync_excel_with_db()
```

run these commands
celery -A my_app.tasks.celery:celery_app beat
celery -A my_app.tasks.celery:celery_app worker

and got an error

The delivery info for this task is:
{'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:.....\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 642, in on_task_received
strategy = strategies[type_]
KeyError: 'sync_excel_with_db'

I tried to explicitly assign a name to the task, but that didn't work either.

Comment: That looks like you are trying to run Celery on Windows. - Celery does not officially support Windows. Some stuff may work, but who knows...